# UWP ThreadPoolTimer wait until work item finished

Tags: c#, timer, uwp, threadpool, periodic-task

I need to implement a periodic timer (10 seconds), that will check for some changes and update Database and UI. I need to wait until "Job" is finished and then start timer again. I call

```
timer.Cancel()
```

on "Job" starting and then create timer again on finish. But seems when I use work-item handlers that use the async keyword ,the thread pool work item may be set to the complete state before all of the code in the handler has executed.
See full code :

```
    private bool IsStop = false;

    private async Task  DoWork()
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsStop)
            {
                Stop();
                return;
            }
            timer.Cancel();
            var resultIds = await DB.getUnresolvedData();

            if (resultIds.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                return;
            }
            var json = await server.RequestSTatus(resultIds);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
                return;
            Model result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json);
            UpdateDB(result);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        finally
        {
            Start();
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (IsStop) return;

        timer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(async (t) =>
        {
            await DoWork();
        }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }
```

The question is ,how I can wait until "Job" is finished and then start again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it little bit different. but code will be more clear and you will use ThreadPool anyway. Just use Task.Delay for timer. Something like this.

```
    private bool isRunning;

    public async void Start()
    {
        if (isRunning)
            return;

        isRunning = true;
        while (isRunning)
        {
            await DoWork();
            //wait period.
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            if (!isRunning)
                return;
        }
    }

    private async Task DoWork()
    {
        //Do your work here.
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        isRunning = false;
    }
```

It is just a general idea.

Comment: I was using 
`private bool IsStop = false;` to stop worker global , like `Pause()` on App Suspending